# Getting error autocomplete is not a function while fetching data from api?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using Jquery to fetch remote data but **getting error**

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function.

I have tried a lot but did not find out the issue behind this I think must be an error in the library.

Using API: [link](https://myimpact.in/deletearticle/services/publication.php) also not fetching data from API

Data is coming in form of  **Json:**

```
    [{"PubId":"1","Title":"Punjab Kesari","Place":"1"}]
```

Code:

```js
//But it is not fetching data
$(function() {
  $("#pub").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://myimpact.in/deletearticle/services/publication.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: request,
        dataType: "JSON",
        minLength: 2,
        success: function(data) {
          response($.map(data, function(el) {
            return {
              label: el.Title,
              value: el.PubId
            };
          }));
        }
      });
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      this.value = ui.item.label;
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="input-group">
    <label class="label"> Publication </label>
    <input class="input--style-4" type="text" id="pub" name="publication">
    <div id="pub"> </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The code you've posted (or as close as I could come to it) seems to be working fine. https://jsbin.com/hiyavobojo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @RockySims Please check  [My-Webpage](https://myimpact.in/deletearticle/services/index.php) and click on publication field you can see error in console, I think too method is correct but don't know where I am going wrong

Comment: @RockySims still getting error please check my [code](https://myimpact.in/deletearticle/services/index.php) once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be 2 scenarios …

1. You are calling the **autocomplete** function before calling the
   jQuery library.
2. Another version of jQuery is included with the other version.

You can use the below code in your query. I hope it will resolve the issue.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you John I have extra jquery of different version now removed and error gone, but still autocomplete not working [link](https://myimpact.in/deletearticle/services/publication.php) this is api and I need to fetch **Title** and **PubId** from it

Comment: show me the webpage link too. so i can see what is the issue there.

Comment: [webpage](https://myimpact.in/deletearticle/services/index.php)  please click on publication field

Comment: Error here -> this.value = ui.item.label;

Comment: You need to get thought by printing item. what is in it and then proceed to label

Comment: I need to print only **Title** but it is giving error

Comment: These are too much records, you need to do some alternative for this. its about 1.5 MB of data that is calling.

Comment: John I really appreciates if you can check code again and api and suggest me how to get desire result, autocomplete title in publication field from api

Comment: First of all try to do one thing. the parameter term that is passing a value is not working, its fetching all the records rather than just for that specific term value

Comment: Now I have limited the requests

Comment: It works like a charm when i limited the data

Comment: Great. Accept the answer if it helps you.